# Black code and no syntax highlighting with Source Code Pro

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using the [Source Code Pro](https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-code-pro) font, and as of Big Sur, all my text is black, even with the Dark+ theme, and there's no syntax highlighting.

[image: screenshot of black-on-dark text]

I tried disabling all extensions and starting Code with `code --disable-gpu`, but neither of these helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to update your Source Code Pro font to the latest release:

- Open Font Book, and in the "User" tab, delete Source Code Pro.
- Download the [latest Source Code Pro release](https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-code-pro/releases). You probably want the OTF version.
- Unpack it, select all `.otf` file, and open them. Then in Font Book, press "Install".

The reason why it broke seems to be related to how Big Sur handles fonts with SVG tables. This is fixed as of the November 2020 release, whose release notes state:

> Removes SVG table to allow for color-coded text in text editing apps. (issue [#250](https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-code-pro/issues/250))